# 2 Ajax divs conflicting

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I use this code and the other td's have the same showDetails code

```
echo '<td width=25 onclick="toggleSlijtd('.$row['id'].')"><img title="'.htmlentities($lang['slijtdeel_minus']).'" src="images/icon/arrow_minus.png"></td>
    <td width=25 align="right" onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails('.$row['id'].');">'.$row['aantal_huidig'].'</td>';
```

showDetails makes the panel come down with some more information, the toggleSlijtd makes the number decrease by one. They are working but:

2. the new number is shown in the wrong place;
3. the new number is only shown when showDetails is used once;

[image]

What is wrong with my code? Or should I use an other code completely. I hope not because time is running out.

My Ajax script:

```
var xmlhttp;

var hold_rowid="";

function toggleSlijtd(str)
{
hold_rowid=str;

xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
  return;
  }
var url="includes/js/ajax_toggle_slijtdeel.php";
url=url+"?q="+str;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{
document.getElementById("row"+hold_rowid).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;  //this now identifies which cell to target and change.
}
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
return null;
}
```

php file:

```
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$id = $_GET["q"];

    $sql = "SELECT aantal_huidig FROM slijtdelen WHERE id = '".$id."' ";
    $query = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());

// Verminder hoeveelheid

while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $hoeveelheid = ($myrow['aantal_huidig'] - 1);
}

$sql="UPDATE slijtdelen SET aantal_huidig = '".$hoeveelheid."' WHERE id = '".$id."' "; 
$query = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());


// Stuur wel of geen icoon terug
if($hoeveelheid > 0)
{
    echo '<td width=25 onclick="toggleSlijtd('.$row['id'].')"><img title="'.htmlentities($lang['slijtdeel_minus']).'" src="images/icon/arrow_minus.png"></td>
          <td width=25 align="right">'.$hoeveelheid.'</td>';
}
else
{
    echo '';
}    
?>
```

Rendered page:

```
  </table><table id="top_header" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">

  <tr class="top_table floating header">

      <td width=10 class="top_table_start"></td>

      <td width=100>Bestelnr. <a href="/slijtdelen.php?sort_name=slt.bestelnummer&sort=asc" title="Sorteer oplopend"><img src="images/icon/asc.png" ></a> <a href="/slijtdelen.php?sort_name=slt.bestelnummer&sort=desc" title="Sorteer aflopend"><img src="images/icon/desc.png" ></a></td>

      <td width=350>Omschrijving <a href="/slijtdelen.php?sort_name=slt.omschrijving&sort=asc" title="Sorteer oplopend"><img src="images/icon/asc.png" ></a> <a href="/slijtdelen.php?sort_name=slt.omschrijving&sort=desc" title="Sorteer aflopend"><img src="images/icon/desc.png" ></a></td>

      <td width=100 colspan="3">Voorraad <a href="/slijtdelen.php?sort_name=slt.aantal_huidig&sort=asc" title="Sorteer oplopend"><img src="images/icon/asc.png" ></a> <a href="/slijtdelen.php?sort_name=slt.aantal_huidig&sort=desc" title="Sorteer aflopend"><img src="images/icon/desc.png" ></a></td>

      <td width=100 colspan="2">In bestelling <a href="/slijtdelen.php?sort_name=slt.in_bestelling&sort=asc" title="Sorteer oplopend"><img src="images/icon/asc.png" ></a> <a href="/slijtdelen.php?sort_name=slt.in_bestelling&sort=desc" title="Sorteer aflopend"><img src="images/icon/desc.png" ></a></td>

      <td width=125 colspan="2">Prijs per stuk <a href="/slijtdelen.php?sort_name=slt.prijs &sort=asc" title="Sorteer oplopend"><img src="images/icon/asc.png" ></a> <a href="/slijtdelen.php?sort_name=slt.prijs &sort=desc" title="Sorteer aflopend"><img src="images/icon/desc.png" ></a></td>

      <td width=150>Catagorie <a href="/slijtdelen.php?sort_name=cat.catagorie&sort=asc" title="Sorteer oplopend"><img src="images/icon/asc.png" ></a> <a href="/slijtdelen.php?sort_name=cat.catagorie&sort=desc" title="Sorteer aflopend"><img src="images/icon/desc.png" ></a></td>

      <td width=150>Leverancier <a href="/slijtdelen.php?sort_name=adr.klantnaam&sort=asc" title="Sorteer oplopend"><img src="images/icon/asc.png" ></a> <a href="/slijtdelen.php?sort_name=adr.klantnaam&sort=desc" title="Sorteer aflopend"><img src="images/icon/desc.png" ></a></td>

      <td width=10 class="top_table_end"></td>

  </tr><tr onMouseOver="addHighlight(this);" onMouseOut="removeHighlight(this);">

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(106);"></td>

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(106);">980SUTA12</td>

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(106);">Boor HSSE PV10 980SUTA Ø12</td><td width=25 onclick="toggleSlijtd(106)"><img title="Haal &eacute;&eacute;n uit voorraad" src="images/icon/arrow_minus.png" /></td>

                    <td width=25 align="right" onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(106);">12</td><td width=50 onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(106);"></td><td width=65 onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(106);"></td><td width=35 onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(106);"></td><td width=75 align="right">&euro; 21.02</td><td width=50 onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(106);"></td>

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(106);"></td>

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(106);">Heku Tools</td>

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(106);"></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

          <td colspan="13"> <div id="details106"></div> </td>

      </tr><tr onMouseOver="addHighlight(this);" onMouseOut="removeHighlight(this);">

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(104);"></td>

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(104);">980SUTA121</td>

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(104);">Boor HSSE PV10 980SUTA Ø12,1</td><td width=25 onclick="toggleSlijtd(104)"><img title="Haal &eacute;&eacute;n uit voorraad" src="images/icon/arrow_minus.png" /></td>

                    <td width=25 align="right" onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(104);">4</td><td width=50 onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(104);"></td><td width=65 onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(104);"></td><td width=35 onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(104);"></td><td width=75 align="right">&euro; 39.32</td><td width=50 onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(104);"></td>

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(104);"></td>

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(104);">Heku Tools</td>

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(104);"></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

          <td colspan="13"> <div id="details104"></div> </td>

      </tr><tr onMouseOver="addHighlight(this);" onMouseOut="removeHighlight(this);">

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(105);"></td>

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(105);">980SUTA61</td>

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(105);">Boor HSSE PV10 980SUTA Ø6,1</td><td width=25 onclick="toggleSlijtd(105)"><img title="Haal &eacute;&eacute;n uit voorraad" src="images/icon/arrow_minus.png" /></td>

                    <td width=25 align="right" onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(105);">5</td><td width=50 onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(105);"></td><td width=65 onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(105);"></td><td width=35 onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(105);"></td><td width=75 align="right">&euro; 16.09</td><td width=50 onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(105);"></td>

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(105);"></td>

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(105);">Heku Tools</td>

          <td onclick="setHighlighted(this),showDetails(105);"></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

          <td colspan="13"> <div id="details105"></div> </td>

      </tr></table>
```

Comment: your img tag is missing a closing slash (should be `/>` not `>`)

Comment: Post the rendered code i.e. the code that the browser sees.

Comment: @Jaitsu thx, but did not solve the problem

Comment: @amit_g added rendered code to the TS

Answer (score 1):

```
</tr><tr onMouseOver="addHighlight(this);" onMouseOut="removeHighlight(this);"></td>
```

The above line has `</td>` without any `<td>`. This may cause the alignment issue. Your server side code doesn't show this. It could be an erroneous tag. Take it out as the first step.

Comment: @amit_g Ok, changed it to:
echo '<tr onMouseOver="addHighlight(this);" onMouseOut="removeHighlight(this);">
Still the problems

Comment: Check the rendered code again. Post if you can't spot the issue.

Comment: The code you have posted seems to be fine. However, it doesn't show full table. Do you have this somewhere on the web? If not, render the code with two or three records and post the whole table.

Comment: @amit_g I can;t put the page online. I have added some more rows to the rendered code in the TS. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @Muiter, could you please add the table tag also? Also, temporarily update the query or whatever is the data source to have only 3-4 rows. That way you would be able to get the whole table and post it as is.

Comment: @Muiter, Looks ok so far. Where is the element that is updated with the AJAX i.e. the element that has ID=rowNN? document.getElementById("row"+hold_rowid).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

Comment: @amit_g I have tried <div id="row'.$row['id'].'"></div> on several places with no luck

Comment: @Muiter, this is not going to work with trial and error. You have to know where exactly the ajax returned data (HTML) is supposed to be inserted. Also that HTML needs to be in sync with rest of the HTML so that everything lines up correctly. It is very hard to troubleshoot on bits and pieces. It seems you must have had <tr ID="rowNNN" at some point in time when the ajax worked. Add it back. This change needs to happen where you are generating the table.